# Google product taxonomy description

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-product-search

I'm working on a website where I'm showing [**Google product categories**](http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1705911) in a tree control. When user click any of the category, system list the products in that category (using Google product search API's).

I need to show a small description of selected category on page. Example below

**Category** = Animals

**Description** = A living organism that feeds on organic matter, typically having specialized sense organs and nervous system and able to respond rapidly to stimuli.

Any ideas on how should I proceed with this? Where should I start looking for description of all categories ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can get your desired results using following technique.
[www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=animal](http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=animal)

Comment: Didn't worked for http://www.google.com/dictionary/json?callback=a&sl=en&tl=en&q=Live%20Animals